# Drawline offset at both ends

Tags: c#, winforms, drawing

I am trying to draw dotted lines using the `DrawLine` method. However, it adds a slight offset to the ends which makes the lines ugly. How can prevent adding offset to the ends?

```
protected override void OnPaint (PaintEventArgs e) {
   Graphics g = e.Graphics;
   g.DrawLine (Dot, new Point (10, 50), new Point (70, 50));
   g.DrawLine (Dot, new Point (70, 50), new Point (70, 100));
}

Pen Dot = new Pen (Brushes.Black, 2) { DashStyle = DashStyle.Dot };
```

**Output**

[image]

**Intended Result**

[image]

Comment: Here is the [magnified result of drawing](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ARXbp.png). What's wrong with the drawing and what do you expect? (The dotted line is the original dotted drawing and the red line shows the box which you used for drawing.

Comment: @RezaAghaei Why is there an offset? Technically, the lines should coincide since the end point of the first line and the start point of the second line are same.

Comment: You can use the linked image and show unexpected part on the image. Also show what's the expected result. I couldn't understand what's the offset which you mentioned. It's a dotted line with 2 as width how can it be different.

Comment: It is not so much an offset as a remainder when the dots don't fit pixel-perfecty into the give length(s). You may succeed in manipulating either the lines by adding an offset or by using a custom dot width or a combination..

Comment: I think I finally nailed it, please give the improved version a try!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The goal is simple and plausible:

- We want our lines to start end end in a dot.

And the rules of the game are also rather simple:

- Both the dots and the gaps are by default squares.
- All lines are drawn with `PenAlignment.Center`.

Unfortunately the consequences of the combination are rather complicated, so bear with me...

Let's first look at the 1st rule; let's ignore other `DashStyles` and stay with `DashStyle.Dot`. By default each dot and each gap have `Pen.Width` pixels for both sides. This leads right into the first issues:

- If the width of our lines can't be divided by `Pen.Width` we are in trouble.
- To begin and end in a dot we want to have `n` dots and `n-1` gaps.

There is more but let's next look into the 2nd rule; to illustrate it I drew this 10x upscaled image:

[image]

This is the code that created the colored parts:

```
g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Yellow, 15, 15, 10, 10);
g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Orange, 10, 10, 10, 10);
g.DrawLine(Pens.OrangeRed, 10, 5, 40, 5);
using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Red, 2f) { DashStyle = DashStyle.Dot })
    g.DrawLine(pen, 10, 30, 48, 30);
using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Crimson, 2f))
    g.DrawLine(pen, 10, 40, 48, 40);
using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.DarkMagenta, 3f))
    g.DrawLine(pen, 10, 50, 48, 50);
```

Look closely to see how the lines are drawn!

(Aside: You may also want to watch the difference of `DrawRectangle` and `FillRectangle`!)

- The horizontal lines start and end at the right coordinates but they expand either downward (if their Pen.Width = 1) or above and below the y-coodinate.
- Vertical lines would do the same, of course.

The problem is that they just won't fit together at the (outer) edges.

So what can we do? I don't think a `DashOffset` can help. But there is another option to tweak a `Pen`: We can set its `DashPattern` to use **custom values**.

The values we need are two `floats`, containing the **scaling** for the dots and the gaps. By default both values are `1f`. I decided to keep the dots square and modify only the gaps. Here is a function which solves the issue by

- expanding the line width by half a pen width on both sides so the outer edges meet
- expanding the gaps as needed to fit in the line length

Here is the line drawing function; it takes the `Graphics` object, a `Pen`, the two end `Points` and a `byte` that tells us if the line is meant to stand alone or will **connect** to other lines, as in our example cases.

To make a **good connection**, that will work well with **semi-tranparent brushes** we need the ability to skip a dot a at the beginning or end or even both, e.g. when we want to insert a diaogonal line as in my test below.

The skip values are `0` to skip none, `1 or 2` to skip the 1st or last dot and `3` to skip both.  Of course you may want to use an `enumeration` instead.

```
void DrawDottedLine(Graphics g, Pen pen_, Point pa_, Point pb, byte skipDots)
{
    float pw = pen_.Width;
    float pw2 = pen_.Width / 2f;
    Pen pen = (Pen)pen_.Clone();
    // find out directions:
    int sigX = Math.Sign(pb_.X - pa_.X);
    int sigY = Math.Sign(pb_.Y - pa_.Y);
    // move the end points out a bit:
    PointF pa = new PointF(pa_.X - pw2 * sigX, pa_.Y - pw2 * sigY);
    PointF pb = new PointF(pb_.X + pw2 * sigX, pb_.Y + pw2 * sigY);
    // find line new length:
    float lw = (float)(Math.Abs(pb.X - pa.X));
    float lh = (float)(Math.Abs(pb.Y - pa.Y));
    float ll = (float)(Math.Sqrt(lw * lw + lh * lh));
    // dot length:
    float dl = ll / pw;
    // dot+gap count: round to nearest odd int:
    int dc = (int)(2 * Math.Round((dl + 1) / 2) - 1);
    //  gap count:
    int gc = dc / 2 ;
    // dot count:
    dc = gc + 1;
    // gap scaling
    float gs = (ll - dc * pw) / (pw * gc);
    // our custom dashpattern 
    pen.DashPattern = new float[] { 1, gs };
    // maybe skip 1st and/or last dots:
    if (skipDots % 2 == 1) pa = new PointF(pa_.X + pw * sigX, pa_.Y + pw * sigY);
    if (skipDots > 1) pb = new PointF(pb_.X - pw * sigX, pb_.Y - pw * sigY);
    // finally we can draw the line:
    g.DrawLine(pen, pa, pb);
    // dispose of pen clone
    pen.Dispose();
}
```

After some obvious preparations I move the points out a bit and then calculate the number of dots and of gaps for vertical or horizontal lines. Then I calculate the modified the gap scale.

Here is the result, scaled up 4x,  of drawing four lines to form a rectangle with varying pen widths going from `1/3  - 10/3`:

[image]

This is the testbed I used; note the use of semi-transparent black to illustrate how the corners are drawn correctly, i.e. non-overlapping:

```
Pen Dot = new Pen(Color.Black, 1f);
Point pa = new Point(10, 50);
Point pb = new Point(70, 50);
Point pc = new Point(70, 100);
Point pd = new Point(10, 100);

for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++ )
{
    Dot = new Pen(Color.FromArgb(128, Color.Black), i / 3f){ DashStyle = DashStyle.Dot };
    g.TranslateTransform(10, 10);
    DrawDottedLine(g, Dot, pa, pb, 2);
    DrawDottedLine(g, Dot, pb, pc, 2);
    DrawDottedLine(g, Dot, pc, pd, 2);
    DrawDottedLine(g, Dot, pd, pa, 2);
    DrawDottedLine(g, Dot, pd, pb, 3);
}
```

I really wish one could avoid the connection problems by simply using `DrawLines`, but this didn't work and after figuring out this solution I'm not really amazed it didn't..

Answer (score 1):

[image: offset line by width of line]

The coordinates you provide are the point to the top-left positions of the resulting line. So when you are drawing a line that is two pixels wide, you should calculate your begin- and endpoints to include the width of that line.

In this case, you would want to offset the vertical line slightly more to the left and top (by `borderwith` to be precise).

So, by adding (or subtracting) an offset equal to the width of the line, the result is this:

```
protected override void OnPaint (PaintEventArgs e) {
   Graphics g = e.Graphics;
   g.DrawLine (Dot, new Point (10, 50), new Point (70, 50));
   g.DrawLine (Dot, new Point (69, 49), new Point (69, 100));
}

Pen Dot = new Pen (Brushes.Black, 2) { DashStyle = DashStyle.Dot };
```

Comment: I couldn't understand what you're saying. A little bit of code might help.

Comment: 67,49 and 67,100 looks perfect

Comment: @kakkarot, in this case, you'd have to incorporate the fact that the dots have gaps, so offsets could be bigger or smaller based on the point where a dot would start or end.

Comment: Actually all lines drawn are drawn with a Pen.Alignment Center, which  complicates the matter. I think I finally nailed it though..