# TextBox border not being drawn when in a Panel

Tags: c#, winforms

I've been messing around with this Paint method for hours now. This is the cleanest/closest solution I could come up with. I even tried making a custom TextBox Control instead, but I think that's out of my current skill set. FYI I am new to VS and C#, so take it easy on me please.

```
    //Draw Borders around our Controls
    private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {

        //Loops through all our text boxes and draws a border
        //Works fine when the textbox is just in the form.
        foreach (TextBox txt in this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
        {
            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(txt.Location.X, txt.Location.Y, txt.ClientSize.Width, txt.ClientSize.Height);

            rect.Inflate(1, 1);
            ControlPaint.DrawBorder(e.Graphics, rect, Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0), ButtonBorderStyle.Solid);
        }


        //Loops through all Panels and draws a border
        foreach (Panel pnl in this.Controls.OfType<Panel>())
        {
            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(pnl.Location.X, pnl.Location.Y, pnl.ClientSize.Width, pnl.ClientSize.Height);

            rect.Inflate(1, 1);
            ControlPaint.DrawBorder(e.Graphics, rect, Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0), ButtonBorderStyle.Solid);

            //Loops through all our TextBoxes in the Panels and draws a border
            //Not drawing the border around the textbox
            foreach (TextBox txt in pnl.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
            {
                rect = new Rectangle(txt.Location.X, txt.Location.Y, txt.ClientSize.Width, txt.ClientSize.Height);

                rect.Inflate(1, 1);
                ControlPaint.DrawBorder(e.Graphics, rect, Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0), ButtonBorderStyle.Solid);
                txt.Text = "FML";       //Just added this to see if we were interacting with each TextBox, and we are.
            }

        }


        //To simplify the nested loop above I tried to just draw a border directly to textBox2, which is inside a Panel.
        Rectangle rect2 = new Rectangle(textBox2.Location.X, textBox2.Location.Y, textBox2.ClientSize.Width, textBox2.ClientSize.Height);

        rect2.Inflate(1, 1);
        ControlPaint.DrawBorder(e.Graphics, rect2, Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0), ButtonBorderStyle.Solid);
        textBox2.Text = "Hello World";      //Still changing the text, just no border.

    }
```

Comment: I think your border covers under the textbox. To test it you can add this: `textBox2.Hide();` If you using .net 4.5. else hide text box in another way and check if the border is visible or not.

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
YOU should __always__ TAG your questions correctly, not write it in the title! Also: You do know that the size of a drawn rectangle must be increaed by 1 to get the intuitive size.. Is the border not showing at all or are the right and bottom parts missing?

Comment: Thanks for the responses and sorry tagging my post incorectly, I'm currently targeting Winforms.

 I don't think the text box is covering the border because it's drawing it just fine when it's not in a Panel. I'm also using rect.Inflate() to make the border bigger then the text box. Sorry for the limited response I'm currently on my phone.

Comment: Why do you use the Form.Paint when the TextBoxes are not on the form but the Panel??? Use Panel.Paint! ( Or, less clean, use coordinates relative to the form!)

Comment: Thats, a good point you bring up. I assumed all painting being done for the app could be done inside Form.Paint. I will give it a shot when I get home. Thanks again for the response!

Answer (score 0):

You can't see the drawing because your coordinates are off because you mix two things:

- You draw in the `Form.Paint` event, but..
- You use the `Textboxes`' `Locations`, which are relative to the `Panel` they sit in.

You can either

- use the `Panel.Paint` event or..
- calculate the `TextBox` locations to be relative to the `Form`.

For the latter solution you can use the `Rectangle.Offset(Point)` function. Do take the border styles into account; also note that `ClientSize` is the area **inside** the borders only..

The first solution also assumes the `Panel` is transparent and that **no other** controls are between `Panel` and `Form`!

This works for me:

```
rect = new Rectangle(textBox3.Left - 1, textBox3.Top - 1,
                     textBox3.Width + 1, textBox3.Height + 1);
rect.Offset(panel1.Location);
```

Also note that `Rectangle.Inflate(a,b)` will not just increase `Width` by `a` but by `a*2` and also decrease `Left` by `a` etc.

Final note: Do note that there is a [difference of how DrawRectangle and FillRectangle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39830696/drawline-offset-at-both-ends/39841654?s=11|14.0885#39841654) treat the size to draw or fill!

Comment: Painting in the panel instead of the form fixed the issue. Also thanks for the second solution! I may be able to clean up some redundant code later on by using rect.Offset instead.

Comment: If you find the answer useful,  please consider consider [accepting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it..! - I see that you have never done this: Go the the (invisible) checkmark at the top left, below the votes of the answer and click it! It turns green and gains us both a little reputation..

Answer (score -1):

```
https://github.com/vignesh-nethaji/Windows-Custom-Controls/blob/master/Menporul.Windows/Menporul.Windows.Controls/Controls/MenTextBox.cs

using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;


namespace Menporul.Windows.Controls
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Menporul TextBox
    /// </summary>
    /// <author>Vignesh Nethaji</author>
    public class MenTextBox : TextBox
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Border Color when textbox focus
        /// </summary>
        private Color _focusBorderColor = Color.Blue;
        /// <summary>
        /// Default Border Color 
        /// </summary>
        private Color _defaultBorderColor = Color.Gray;
        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        public MenTextBox()
        {


        }
        /// <summary>
        /// On control resize refresh the control for Border rendering based on the control size
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        protected override void OnSizeChanged(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnSizeChanged(e);
            this.Refresh();
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Getting device context for creating graphics for draw border on textbox
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="hwnd"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        [DllImport("user32")]
        private static extern IntPtr GetWindowDC(IntPtr hwnd);
        /// <summary>
        /// Draw textbox border when its painting 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="m"></param>
        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
        {
            base.WndProc(ref m);
            if (m.Msg == 0x85 || m.Msg == 0x000F)
            {
                Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, Width, Height);
                if (this.Focused)
                {

                    var dc = GetWindowDC(Handle);
                    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromHdc(dc))
                    {
                        ControlPaint.DrawBorder(g, rect,
                       _focusBorderColor, 2, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid,
                       _focusBorderColor, 2, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid,
                       _focusBorderColor, 2, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid,
                       _focusBorderColor, 2, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid);
                    }
                }
                else
                {

                    var dc = GetWindowDC(Handle);
                    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromHdc(dc))
                    {
                        ControlPaint.DrawBorder(g, rect,
                       _defaultBorderColor, 1, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid,
                       _defaultBorderColor, 1, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid,
                       _defaultBorderColor, 1, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid,
                       _defaultBorderColor, 1, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid);
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: SO expects you to include comments or explanations not just a piece of code.

Comment: Thanks for the custom TextBox example Vignesh. I may refer back to this at a later date. I would prefer to make a handful of custom controls for my project instead of handling all my styling with Form.Paint but I am currently not able to write them myself so this will have to do for now.

Comment: On a side note, how did you go about figuring that out? Is it just an altered version from the base code? It looks pretty straight forward to me until the WndProc function.