# Set custom spacing in winforms ChartDashStyle

Tags: c#, winforms, charts

Is there a way to customize the spacing in a `ChartDashStyle.Dash` dash style?

I'm plotting several series with solid, dash and dot styles, but when my graph is too small the dash and dot styles look like a solid line.

I only managed to get the spacing more obvious by increasing the `BorderWidth` parameter, but it then the line's widths are really too wide.

I initially plotted the lines with a small width : [the dashes are not spaced enough](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7RLsV.png)

I then increased the series' border width : [the lines are too wide (and still the dashes look too close to each other](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tG0ZB.png)

Is there a way to specify a custom dash style, as it seems to exist for the Pen class?

Comment: I don't think this possible with the built-in drwing. But you can do a [custom drawing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43667315/how-to-put-a-logarithmic-scale-with-rows-represented-in-logarithm-on-chart-in-c/43668927#43668927) of the lines and use a pen with a [custom dashstyle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39830696/drawline-offset-at-both-ends/39841654#39841654).

Comment: Another example of [custom drawing the chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37465005/how-can-i-fill-the-areas-between-two-series-of-splines-or-lines/37465012#37465012)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll look into it. I had the feeling that it wasn't possible and that it would require (if possible) a workaround using a Pen, but I couldn't find a way around. That will help! 

One additional question tho: I'd like the lines to appear in the legend. Is there a way to customize the legend with a custom Pen? If I straightforwardly put my series in the legend, it will not display the proper line since I draw it afterwards, right?

Comment: Yes you can create a CustomLegend and display anything you like in it. A bit tricky, though.. - [Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A3152130+chart+legend+custom)